# A little bit of trouble with 2D arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to convert a basic game I made in Java to HTML5 for learning purposes; However I'm having a little trouble, I would provide a runnable example, but I'm using the Phaser engine, and my codes quite spread out. I'm trying to follow an OO approach in Javascript, either way here's my code.

**Creating the array:**

```
function newArray2D(rows, columns) {
    var x = new Array(rows);
    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        x[i] = new Array(columns);
    }
    return x;
}
```

-

```
tiles = newArray2D(Math.ceil(game.width / 64), Math.ceil(game.height / 64));
```

**Populating the array:**

```
for(var x = 0; x < tiles.length; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < tiles[0].length; y++) {
        tiles[x][y] = new Tile(x * 64, y * 64);
    }
}
```

**The Tile "class":**

```
var x, y, width, height;

function Tile(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = 64;
    this.height = 64;
}

function hovering(mouseX, mouseY) {
    if((mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + width)
            && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y + height))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**The error:**

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

**The code causing the error:**

```
for(var x = 0; x < tiles.length; x++) {
    for(var y = 0; y < tiles[0].length; y++) {
        if(tiles[x][y].hovering(game.input.mousePointer.x, game.input.mousePointer.y)) {
            tileDebug.text = 'Tile('+x+','+y+')';
        }
    }
}
```

**The line of code triggering the error:**

```
if(tiles[x][y].hovering(game.input.mousePointer.x, game.input.mousePointer.y)) {
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, as the debug console doesn't really give much more information than "undefined is not a function"... But the function I'm calling is "hovering", isn't it? Perhaps I'm creating the array wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't assigned the `hovering` method to the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of your `Tile` "class". Give this a try:

```
Tile.prototype.hovering = function(mouseX, mouseY) {
    if((mouseX > this.x && mouseX < (this.x + this.width)
            && mouseY > this.y && mouseY < (this.y + this.height))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, you could keep your definition of `hovering` as-is, and pass in the `Tile` object as an additional parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to ask for the prototype link when you edited, the problem now is that x/y are also undefined, `Called(undefined,undefined)` printed when `console.log("Called("+x+","+y+")");` is ran in the hovering method.

Comment: Also, a little bit unrelated to the code itself, but with a little bit of clever math, you could just calculate which tile is hovered over without looping over all the tiles (which might be inefficient).

Comment: Thanks! The prototype link doesn't explain very well as to why the 'this' keyword is used, in Java it's used to get the instance of the variable in the class scope, but it's not required, does it have the same functionality here, but it is required?

Comment: Yeah, probably could, I'm just using this to make sure I have everything being laid out right, before moving onto rendering.

Comment: `this` in Javascript has functionality similar to its Java equivalent, but it is indeed required.

Answer (score 0):

You've created `hovering` as a function in the global JS namespace.

Try changing the declaration of the function to:

```
newArray2D.hovering = function (mouseX, mouseY) {
    if((mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + width)
            && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y + height))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```